# How do you restrict the scaling of the sine wave upto certain value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below codes so as to scale up the amplitude of the sine wave after the limit value 20.Here I am not able to restrict the amplitude of the sine wave.Please refer the figure below.I need the output as mentioned in figure in single plot window[not via subplot]. I need only amplitude scaling not the frequency scaling.Could any one help me in this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Limit=20

x=np.linspace(-20,20,400)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)

y[(y<=Limit)] = y*0.5
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you want a plot as shown, shouldn't your x values be from 0 to 40? Also, shouldn't your condition be `y[x <= Limit]`, since you want to scale everything before a certain _x_ value, not within a certain _y_ value?

Comment: Your description doesn't match the figure. Both x and y limits are wrong. Also, if it's just scaling, why does the line drop off immediately at 20? Scaling wouldn't do that.

Comment: You can change the limit value to 10 and check.It is still not possible to restrict the amplitude scaling.

Comment: Your code does not produce the image that you included. It actually produces [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RIqnI.png)

Comment: @Eric: Please read my question properly "Please refer the figure below.I need the output as mentioned in figure in single plot window[not via subplot]."

Comment: @HEMS: Everyone so far has read your question incorrectly. Perhaps it needs clarifying. Why do you include a picture that is neither your desired output nor your actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_limit = 20

x = np.linspace(0,40,400)
y = np.sin(x)
y[x <= x_limit] *= 0.5
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I think you wanted to apply the limit to the x, not the y.

[image]

Comment: :Output is not as mentioned in the figure above

Comment: :Absolutely yes.This meets the amplitude scaling requirement even during the dynamic shift of the x_limit on the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done relatively straightforward as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Limit=20

x=np.linspace(-20,20,4000)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x[x<0],y[x<0], lw=2, color='k')

y[(y<=Limit)] = y*0.5
plt.plot(x[x>0],y[x>0], lw=2, color='k')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image: Output from the example code]

Comment: I am getting smoother transition between two waves when the limit is zero.This is good.If there is a dynamic shift of limit to the either side of zero on x axis[-10 or +10], there is discontinuity in the sine wave [break in signal] which is not good.